# UDP Sender / Receiver : receiver not receiving data

Tags: java, udp

I used the code from Erwin Bolwidt here [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39526315/java-udp-receiver-not-receiving-data?newreg=bb26147ae2d24277b2f6ac879dd137ba)

I tried from my PC (firewall disabled). Why the program don't receive my UDP packet ?

Here's the code :

```
package udp;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String desktopPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator +"Desktop" + File.separator +"fifa.properties";
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new FileInputStream(desktopPath));
        
        int port = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("PORT"));
        
        
        new Main().run(port);
    }

    public void run(int port) {    
      try {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[8];
        String sendString = "fifa";
        byte[] sendData = sendString.getBytes("UTF-8");

        System.out.printf("Listening on udp:%s:%d%n",
                InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), port);     
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                           receiveData.length);

        while(true)
        {
              serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
              String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData(), 0,
                                 receivePacket.getLength() );
              System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
              // now send acknowledgement packet back to sender     
              DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length,
                   receivePacket.getAddress(), receivePacket.getPort());
              serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
              
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println(e);
      }
      // should close serverSocket in finally block
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance

Tried to send and receive UDP packet from same computer. My PC don't receive anything

Comment: There is too much unknown here. What IP address are you using "from same computer": localhost, LAN IP, external IP from router? How do you send data? Did you check that the data actually get send from your client? Try using wireshark to observe what is actually happening.

Comment: I see one program here, which looks like the server. Where's the client code?